# Dynamic favicon when I'm proccessing ajax data

Tags: jquery, dynamic, favicon

I've got problems when trying to show loading favicon.

I'm taking facebook as example. When you do go to facebook homepage and then click "Messages", it does change favicon (as reloading/redirecting), but page is still same. How do they do that?

Comment: My comment is based on what I'm seeing in [the image you linked to](http://uloziste.eu/pictures/8e9979379aedb45a2206be98ebaad4ae.png) in your comment to **devmatt's** answer.  The "loading" animation in the tab is part of the browser/os and not part of the site.  In a Firefox tab, the "loading" animation is in the same location as the favicon.  In a Safari tab, there is no favicon and the "loading" animation is on the right side of the tab's text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my favicon problem - simple iframe

```
<body>
  <iframe id="frameFix" src="something.php" name="frameFix" height="0" width="0".
  border="0" ></iframe>
  <a href="new.php" target="frameFix">new thing (page will start to "load")</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax, you can get contents of a url and dump it onto the website without having to leave the page,

as for your first question Favicon its cached and it's not easy to change it dynamically, as the user must force refresh, but my advise is that a favicon its meant to be the same to identify your website, to each user while the have minimised it, therefore if you keep changing them you lose your websites identity kinda thing :)

Comment: I know I do not have to leave page, but how do I change adress-bar content? However, facebook just change favicon to "reloading", classic reloading icon which is showing in FF when you're being redirected

Comment: I think that reloading is the browser and not so much your website. but I will double check that for you

Comment: did you tried that thing I described in question, on facebook?

Comment: @genesis:  I'm in Safari and my favicon on Facebook does **not** do what you describe.  The "loading" animation in the tab that [you linked to as an example](http://uloziste.eu/pictures/8e9979379aedb45a2206be98ebaad4ae.png), is part of the browser and not the site.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok. so could you please try it in FF ?

Comment: @genesis:  If it wasn't obvious from the comments I made under your original question, I'll say it again.  The Facebook "loading" icon I see on my Firefox tab is different than what [you posted here](http://uloziste.eu/pictures/8e9979379aedb45a2206be98ebaad4ae.png); it does not come from Facebook.