# URL change ajax call in Facebook

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, iframe

In facebook, whenever you navigate to a different URL (in some situations), the URL changes but there is no feeling sensed as going to a different page.

For example: when we view pictures in facebook, and when we move to the next image the URL changes in the address bar

FROM >facebook.com/foo?bar=foobar&xxxx=

TO > >>facebook.com/foo?bar=boobar&xxxx=

and this is not hashed change also
like

FROM >facebook.com/xxxxx#xxx=xxxx

TO > >>facebook.com/xxxxx#xxx=yyyy

How is this possible seamlessly. I mean how is that only a container is modified on URL change. URL change is supposed to navigate to a different page which can contain cached information from previous page and THIS navigation by URL change can be seen obviously by browser's screen going blank for a moment.

If using an iFrame, how to implement this ?

Comment: They are using the HTML5 History API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow. I just asked it few minutes ago ... use search next time ;)

[Dynamic favicon when I'm proccessing ajax data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228359/dynamic-favicon-when-im-proccessing-ajax-data)

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1):

I use somehting similar to this

```
try {
  var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
  history.pushState(stateObj, "page", href);
  loadPage(href);
}
catch(e) {
  window.location.hash = "#!/"+href;
}
```

If it supports the HTML5 pushState them change URL, but if it doesn't then the fall back is the window hash.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin called "address" that will watch for changes and call the function you give.  I think it's just checking the URL every 100ms or so.

Answer (score 0):

They issue an AJAX request for the data necessary to fulfil the "navigation", then tell the browser to "go to #xxx=yyy". Since such an anchor doesn't exist, the browser doesn't actually scroll down. However, it does record a new history entry, and also updates the URL so that if someone copy-pastes that URL, they will view the same object that the user is seeing, rather than just the original page.